# qgis.core import error

Tags: pyqgis, installation

I would want to use the Qgis api for custom desktop application. When I imported the qgis.core module, I get the following error

```
>>> import qgis.core 
Traceback (most recent call last):   
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module> 
ImportError: DLL load failed: The
specified module could not be found.
```

A similar error was reported in the forums,im not sure if the exact solution was reached.

[Python :ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/19257/python-importerror-dll-load-failed-the-specified-module-could-not-be-found)

Forums do suggest that I would have to use the OSGeo Version of python. How would i get to choose the version of python to use?

I think this could be a path or a pythonpath.Have given my path and python path information below.Let me know if I had missed any of the directories that should be added for qgis core to get its dependencies met.

`PATH=C:\Python26;C:\Python26\Scripts;C:\Python26\ArcGIS10.0;C:\Python26\ArcGIS10.0\Scripts;C:\OSGeo4W\apps\qgis-dev\bin`

`PYTHONPATH=C:\Python26;C:\OSGeo4W\apps\qgis\python;C:\OSGeo4W\apps\python27;C:\Python26\ArcGIS10.0;C:\Python26\Lib\site-packages`