# qgis.core error

Tags: python, pyqgis

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [qgis.core import error](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/28224/qgis-core-import-error)

I am new in quantum gis and python,
I installed quantum gis 1.8 from osgeo4w installer, after I installed python 2.7 and started python shell and write this code:

```
from qgis.core import *
```

and obtain this error:

```
ImportError: DLL load failed no module found
```

Previously I added in config.sys of windows xp this:

```
set PYTHONPATH=c:\osgeo4w\apps\python
set PATH:c:\osgeo4w\bin;%PATH%
```

what the problem? 
p.s. in quantum gis when I write this command in python console I do not have this problem

Comment: This is a FAQ: please [research the previous answers](http://gis.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=%2bdll%20%2bload%20%2bfailed).