# Importing fmeobjects into PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, fme-form, fmeobjects

I use FME a lot for manipulation of spatial data, and would like to leverage it's Python library, fmeobjects in PyQgis.

If I run the following in my standard Python IDE it works fine:

```
import sys 
sys.path.append("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\fme\\fmeobjects\\python27") 
import fmeobjects
```

But the exact same code, when run in PyQgis, throws
    ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

In actual fact, fmeobjects is a .pyd file. I don't know if that's the problem, as my understanding is that pyd and dll are analogous to each other.

How can I get fmeobjects to import into PyQgis?

Comment: You mean when run in python console in QGIS?

Comment: Yes, sorry if I wasn't clear. I'm running the above as a .py script saved in the editor.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? i'm having the same problem

Answer (score 4):

2016 update! Been trying to get this to work myself and thought I'd put what I've researched so far. This is done on Windows 10. For Linux users - try [this](https://knowledge.safe.com/questions/21273/run-fmeobjects-on-linux.html) if you're encountering problems.

Warning: For those wanting to integrate FME 2016 into python qgis, know that it isn't as easy as 'pip install fmeobjects' :)

---

Step 1

Locate your fmeobjects.pyd file. This I think is the hardest part really! See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8822335/what-do-the-python-file-extensions-pyc-pyd-pyo-stand-for) for an intro to .pyd files. It's basically a Python Windows DLL file.

For Python 2.7 the file should be at:

```
C:\apps\FME2016\fmeobjects\python27\fmeobjects.pyd
```

QGIS doesn't use Python3 yet as of now, but if it does in upcoming QGIS 3 version, you should use:

```
C:\apps\FME2016\fmeobjects\python34\fmeobjects.pyd
```

For me, the file was located at D:\apps\FME2016\fmeobjects\python27\fmeobjects.pyd. So search around until you find that file.

---

Step 2

Next, let's import the fmeobjects module! The most official documentation I can find is [here](https://knowledge.safe.com/articles/302/errors-fmeworkspacerunner-python-errors-fmeobjects.html), note that it refers to FME 2015, but it should work on 2016. In 'theory', the following code should work:

```
import sys
sys.path.append("C:\\apps\\FME2016\\fmeobjects\\python27")
import fmeobjects
```

**Advanced**

If you are getting the error "ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found", see [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/19259/78212).

Now, if you're keen, you can go to http://www.dependencywalker.com/, download the application (it's portable) and search for your fmeobjects.pyd file, and run it

[image: fmeobjects.pyd in dependencywalker]
[image: fmeobjects.pyd in dependencywalker]

See how fme.dll, fmepython27.dll, fmeutil.dll and rwtool_fme.dll are yellow in the second image? Those are missing dependencies not in our sys.path.

Those four files appear to located in a higher level directory (D:\apps\FME2016\ in my case). So we add that top-level directory to our sys.path, and also cd (change directory) to where fme is located so that fmeobjects will load properly. The python script thus becomes:

```
import os
import sys
sys.path.append("C:\\apps\\FME2016\\fmeobjects\\python27")
sys.path.append("C:\\apps\\FME2016\\")                     #add this
os.chdir("C:\\apps\\FME2016\\")        #do this too (somehow needed)
import fmeobjects
```

---

Step 3

Verify that things work.

```
licMan = fmeobjects.FMELicenseManager()               # Print FME license type.
print 'FME License Type :', licMan.getLicenseType()   # FME license property names.
```

Note: if you get the error "FMEException: FMEException: -1:" here, I think that means your python script is not running on the same machine as FME Desktop. E.g. your code is on your local drive but FME is installed on a server.

---

Step 4

[Run a workbench](https://knowledge.safe.com/questions/2030/run-workbench-from-external-python.html)!

```
worker = fmeobjects.FMEWorkspaceRunner()
worker.run('D:/fme/Workspaces/test.fmw')
```

---

Step 5

Immerse yourself in the [API](http://docs.safe.com/fme/html/FME_Objects_Python_API/index.html).

---

Personally, I run my script over and over again alot, so I have some if-then statements and try-except stuff:

```
import sys
fmePydPath = "C:\\apps\\FME2016\\fmeobjects\\python27"      #fme file path
fmePath = "C:\\apps\\FME2016\\"
if fmePydPath not in sys.path: sys.path.append(fmePydPath)  #prevents too much appending
if fmePath not in sys.path: sys.path.append(fmePath)

os.chdir(fmePath)
import fmeobjects

#Verifies that things work
licMan = fmeobjects.FMELicenseManager()               # Print FME license type.
print 'FME License Type :', licMan.getLicenseType()   # FME license property names.

#Runs a workspace (.fmw) file
try:
    worker = fmeobjects.FMEWorkspaceRunner()
    worker.run('D:/fme/Workspaces/test.fmw')
except fmeobjects.FMEException, err:
    print "FMEException: %s" % err
```

Answer (score 0):

In Windows QGIS has its own Python version. By default if you instal libraries (ex. `pip install name_of_library`) it will be installed only in your pure Python version not for QGIS.

Here is a guide, I think it may be helpful: http://quantumofgis.blogspot.be/2014/11/qgis-standalone-and-python-modules.html

Comment: IIRC, I didn't pip install the FME Objects library to my main Python install. My understanding is (was) that I used the sys.path.append method detailed above to graft FME Objects from the location specified to the path of the interpreter executing the script. Am I incorrect in that thinking?

Answer (score 0):

Try copying the fmeobjects.pyd to QGIS site.

From:

\fmeobjects\python27\fmeobjects.pyd

To:

\Lib\site-packages\fmeobjects.pyd

Comment: Yep - tried that but no luck