# Importing fmeobjects module into python script

Tags: python, versioning, fmeobjects, modulenotfounderror

I've tried doing doing what [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/153539/importing-fmeobjects-into-pyqgis) post suggests but still get errors.

This code:

```py
import sys

sys.path.append(r"C:\\Program Files\\FME\\fmeobjects\\python37")
sys.path.append(r"C:\\Program Files\\FME\\")
os.chdir(r"C:\\Program Files\\FME\\")

import fmeobjects
```

returns "ImportError: DLL load failed while importing fmeobjects: The specified module could not be found."

When I try to install the module in cmd line with pip I get the following:

```
C:\Users\name>pip install fmeobjects
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement fmeobjects (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for fmeobjects
```

I'm using python 3.11.3 as my interpreter... do I need to make a virtual env using a 3.7 interpreter?